# Is it possible to find such a $f$?

Tags: elementary-functions

I search a continuous function $f : [0,+\infty[ \to \mathbb{R}$ such as : $\lim \limits_{x\to +\infty} \frac{1}{x} \int \limits_{0}^{x} f(t)\mathrm{d}t=\pm \infty$ and ($\lim \limits_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=l\in \mathbb{R}$ or $f$ does not have limits).

First I know that it doesn't work with monotone functions. Then I start to try with $x\mapsto cos(x)^2$ but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I think you mean "monotone" or (synonymously) "monotonic": "monotonous" means "boring". Or maybe that is what you meant $\ddot{\smile}$? More seriously, why do you think $f$ can't be monotone?

Comment: Try $x\cos^2(x)$.

Comment: @RobArthan because of the monotone limit theorem. Same for sequences

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you !!

Comment: So what in your criteria excludes the monotone function $f(t) = t$?

Comment: @RobArthan It works with this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us look at the two cases:

1. Let us prove there is no continuous function $f : [0,+\infty[ \to \mathbb{R}$ such as : $\lim \limits_{x\to +\infty} \frac{1}{x} 
   \int \limits_{0}^{x} f(t)\mathrm{d}t=\pm \infty$ and $\lim \limits_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=l\in \mathbb{R}$

If $f : [0,+\infty[ \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and $\lim \limits_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=l\in \mathbb{R}$, it is easy to prove that $f$ is bounded. So there are $M$ such that, for all $x\in [0,+\infty[\,$, $\vert f(x) \vert \leq M$. So, for all $x\in [0,+\infty[\,$,
$$\left\vert\frac{1}{x} 
\int \limits_{0}^{x} f(t)\mathrm{d}t\right \vert\leq \frac{1}{x} 
\int \limits_{0}^{x} \vert f(t) \vert \mathrm{d}t \leq M$$
So we can NOT have $\lim \limits_{x\to +\infty} \frac{1}{x} 
\int \limits_{0}^{x} f(t)\mathrm{d}t=\pm \infty$.

2. On the other hand, it is rather easy to present examples of continuous functions $f : [0,+\infty[ \to \mathbb{R}$ such as : $\lim \limits_{x\to +\infty} \frac{1}{x} 
   \int \limits_{0}^{x} f(t)\mathrm{d}t=\pm \infty$ and $f$ does not have limits.

Example 1: Define $f(x)=x(1+\sin(x))$

Example 2: [from David C. Ullrich comment] Define $f(x)=x\cos^2(x)$

Answer (score 0):

If  $l$ exists, then for any positive r, choose positive y, where $y<x$ implies $abs(l-f(x))<r$.The integral of f from y to x, for x>y, lies between $(x-y)(l-r)$ and $(x-y)(l+r)$. The integral of f from o to y does not depend on any x that's greater than y. Add them, divide by x, and let x go to infinity. As r can be arbitrarily small, the limit is $l$, not plus or minus infinity.

Comment: You prove that : $\lim \limits_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=l\in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow \lim \limits_{x\to +\infty} \frac{1}{x} \int \limits_{0}^{x} f(t)\mathrm{d}t=l$.